# My Dracaena reflexa (Song of India) is dying. Help!

Tags: diagnosis, indoors, container-gardening, office-gardening, dracaena

Help!

I got this dracaena over a month ago and it was doing well up until this week. This plant stays in an office with just fluorescent lights and is watered once a week. Last week it started getting some new growth up top, but I started to notice some of the leaves were browning. It was mainly the bottom ones so I thought nothing of it.

However this week, more and more leaves started falling off daily and today the center part (with the new growth) just fell off! What am I doing wrong? How can I save my plant?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, but I think just fluorescent light is not sufficient for most plant species. They usually need direct or indirect sunlight, or they should be grown under special grow lamps. I think this plant species can survive in shade but then in proximity of a window (hence indirect sunlight). How far from a window is your plant at the moment? And how dark would your office be if your lights are switched off? Does your office have any windows at all?

Answer (score 2):

More light certainly.  Have you ever fertilized?  If not, which is what I am seeing, get some simple Osmocote extended release fertilizer 14-14-14.  Do half of what the directions direct.  Is this plant in potting soil?  Are there rocks or gravel beneath the soil and drain hole?  That will cause a cessation of critical drainage.  Do not put this plant in direct sunlight even through a window without acclimating it first.  This problem is either too much water or no fertilizer.  Too much water because of a perched water table.  Are you using tap water?  I'd find some bottled water without fluoride!

Answer (score -1):

This is due to bacterial disease. It is difficult to control. Better to remove and destroy as soon as possible

Comment: Welcome Roshan! Please don't get discouraged by that message. It's there because we need more details so people can learn from you. For instance, how can we tell it's bacteria? What part of the question indicates that? Can you please add more text, and post and quote from links if you have them, by using [edit].  Check out [answer] and other parts of our [help] for guidance with our unique system! Leave a note here if we can help you with anything! Thanks for joining us!  We're glad you're here!